# Not able to find application program line causing exception in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly

Wildfly is giving error but cant find which line is causing this error. Can someone help in how to log complete line no causing error.

```
16:13:12,716 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "App.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"App.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: is there any way to on debug ?

Comment: Wildfly sometimes logs errors like this one when the deployment is corrupted for some reason. Sometimes it's enough to *refresh the project, clean it and deploy it again* (or build a new war file using `gradle clean war` or a similar command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to a rest api not able to get mapped/initialized. If you get same error, run wildfly in debug mode, then check the method/api was getting just initialized before this error and failed, that api could be having bad arguments which caused wildfly to give this error and fail on startup.